# Why isn't 到 (dào) used in 某天我去北京?

Tags: verbs, preposition

Earlier while chatting, I wrote a sentence and a native speaker told me it was correct. The sentence was:

> 某天我去北京。= *Someday I'll go to Beijing.*
>   <sub>(mǒu tiān wǒ qù Běi jīng)</sub>

I noticed that no prepositions are used here. It's probably because I'm still a beginner, but then I wondered: if it's true that 到 can mean *"to (a place)"*, why isn't it used in that sentence? Are there some rules I'm not aware of or something I'm missing?

Also: when should we use 到? What are the situations/contexts that need it?

Comment: I am native and 某天我去北京 does NOT have any implication of time. It sounds like an incomplete sentence too, so when I hear it I would be expecting a story that follows (what happened to you in Beijing). That would make it past-tense. If you want to say it in future tense, like how you put it in English. Then you should say 某天我会去北京的。 Essentially "One day, I **will** go to Beijing." Sorry for being off topic but I think its worth pointing out, since there is no go/went/gone (tense embedded in a verb) in Chinese.

Comment: To mean "Someday I'll go to Beijing", and use "到", I'll say: "哪天我要到北京去耍耍".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, grammars of Chinese and English are totally different, you don't need the preposition like in English.

Second, in my opinion, 去 indicates that you start the action of "going to a place",and "到" indicates that you have finished that action, so you "reach a place " or "arrive at a place".

An example:

> 本周二我会坐火车去北京，周三到。
>
> I will  go to Beijing by train this Tuesday and I will arrive on Wednesday.

Comment: I accepted yours because I appreciated the example with both the characters being used... :)

Answer (score 11):

A significant difference between Chinese and English is that sometimes the border between a "verb" and a "preposition" is blurred.  In your case, both "去" and "到" has the meaning of "go", "go to", "reach", or "visit", and therefore can be used interchangeably.

You don't need a preposition if you use a transitive verb to translate "去":
某天我去北京。 = Some day I'll visit Beijing.

Comment: What's the difference between 某天我去北京 and 某天我到北京, then?

Comment: @Alenanno: `<beginner>`The second version (某天我到北京) sounds to me like "I was in Beijing one unspecified day in the past" or maybe "I came to Beijing one day"?`</beginner>` Hopefully, someone will clarify..

Comment: Frank, did you see the question? :)

Answer (score 10):

`到` more or less means "to arrive (at)," `去` means "go to (someplace)."

E.g., 你到18歲才能喝酒。You can drink alcohol, when you are (lit. "arrive at") (the age of) 18.

When used together with `去` (e.g., `到马路那边去`), it tells someone to go somewhere or do something.

Answer (score 2):

Huang and Krazer's answers already point you in the right direction.

I cannot find an example where 到 alone means to go.

You should use 到 (when alone) has you would use the verb arrive in English.

> 到家我要睡觉. When I arrive home (when I am back at home) I need to sleep.
>
> 我到北京了. I arrived at Beijing.

到 indicates a final point, a destination.

It can also be used in combination with 去 to indicate the final destination  of a **journey** (more or less long distance) and thus add the idea of movement, travel.

Note the nuance in the following examples:

> 我去北京. I (will) go to Beijing.
>
> 我到北京去. I (will) travel to Beijing.

Answer (score 1):

某天我去北京 is arguably wrong due to the lack of any indication of tense. I will not be able to determine from this sentence the tense, therefore I will not know what exactly are you trying to say.

某天我去到北京 will be interpreted as past tense, since 去到 essentially means "arrived at".

某天我会去北京的 will be interpreted as future tense. 会+verb means something you are going to do (or have planned to do).

I guess the use of 某天 ruled out present tense.

Also note that, "someday" in English usually indicates a day in the future (Someday, I will beat you in Chess!). However 某天 is **NOT** exactly the same because it can refer to any day, past or future. So 某天 is more like "one day" in English.

So, your sentence would actually be interpreted as:

One day, I [go/went/will go] to Beijing.

Hence the doubt.

Answer (score -1):

某天我去北京 =  某天我将去北京
我将在未来某个目前还没有确定的时间，去北京。